# Some services are not able to be constructed Error while validating the service descriptor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ef-core-5.0

I have a ASP.NET Core 5.0 MVC solution,

```
public abstract class HostedService : IHostedService, IDisposable
{
        private Task _currentTask;
        private readonly CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource = new 
        CancellationTokenSource();

        protected abstract Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken token);


        public virtual Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _currentTask = ExecuteAsync(cancellationToken);
            return _currentTask.IsCompleted ? _currentTask : Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public virtual async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if (_currentTask == null) return;
            try
            {
                _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
            }
            finally
            {
                await Task.WhenAny(_currentTask, Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite, cancellationToken));
            }
        }

        public virtual void Dispose()
        {
            _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        }
}
```

Gets the exchange rates from URL

```
public class ExchangeSyncManager : HostedService
{
        private readonly CurrencyServices _currencyServices;
        private readonly ExchangeRateServices _exchangeRateServices;
        public ExchangeSyncManager(CurrencyServices currencyServices, ExchangeRateServices 
        exchangeRateServices)
        {
            _currencyServices = currencyServices;
            _exchangeRateServices = exchangeRateServices;
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken token)
        {
            // işlem iptal edilmemişse…
            if (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                var url = "http://www.tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/today.xml";
                XmlDocument xmlVerisi = new XmlDocument();
                List<ExchangeRate> list = new List<ExchangeRate>();
                xmlVerisi.Load(url);

                foreach (var currency in _currencyServices.GetCurrencies())
                {
                    var format = string.Format("Tarih_Date/Currency[@Kod='{0}']/ForexSelling", currency.Name);
                    var selectAndReplace = xmlVerisi.SelectSingleNode(format).InnerText.Replace('.', ',');
                    decimal value = Convert.ToDecimal(selectAndReplace);

                    list.Add(new ExchangeRate
                    {
                        Date = DateTime.Now,
                        Value = value,
                        CurrencyId = currency.Id
                    });
                }
                _exchangeRateServices.AddRange(list);

                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromDays(1), token);
            }
        }
}
```

And in startup :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            
            //other services here
            ......................................................
            .....................................................
            services.AddScoped<CurrencyServices, CurrencyServices>();
            services.AddScoped<ExchangeRateServices>();
            services.AddHostedService<ExchangeSyncManager>();
}
```

Still I am getting this error :

Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: IPMMS.Business.Managers.ExchangeSyncManager': Cannot consume scoped service 'IPMMS.Business.Services.CurrencyServices' from singleton 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService'.)'

What is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot inject a scoped services inside a singleton. They are bound to HTTP requests.
A HostedService's lifetime is singleton.
However you can use the IServiceProvider to create a scope and retrieve an instance of your scoped service.

You will find how to fix your issue here :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/scoped-service